# Image not responsive nor resizing to max-width value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am toggling 2 images, a small icon (pic1_off.png)  and a much larger image (pic1_on.png) in a page of text. The 2 images toggle between each other OK, but the larger image is too big. I want it be 40% of page width displaying from the left and to be responsive to screen size changes. The HTML is:

```
<span class="infoToggler"><img class="img-swap" src="/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/books/science_news/hearing_loss/pic1_off.png" align="left"></span>
```

the JS:

```
jQuery(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
    if (jQuery(this).attr("class") === "img-swap") {
        this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
    } else {
        this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
    }
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("on");
});
});
```

CSS:

```
img.img-swap {
    max-width: 40%;
    height: auto;
}
```

I can't work out why the larger image is not resizing nor why it is not responsive. Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: This code is okay, problem is elsewhere.

Comment: which browser are you using for testing?

Comment: max-height does not work on some browsers, i suggest using height:40%; instead

Comment: I've run the page in Firefox 37.0.2 and Chrome 42.0.2311.90 with the same results, height: 40% makes no difference. Any suggestions as to where the problem might be. I should add that the page is part of a Joomla site.

Comment: @RoyS sorry I meant use width:40% instead of max-width:40%;    ;-)

Comment: @Lulando  Yes that works, except that it reduces both the small and the large images to 40%, whereas I just needed the larger one reduced. Also, the text is no longer wrapping around the image. But, still, some progress. Thanks